# tensorflow framework error: duplicate node name in graph: 'ones'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I finally got the tensorflow executor to successfully open the appropriate libraries in the pic below:

[image]

However, it gave me a framework error:
[image]

here are my versions:

cuda 10.1
cudnn 7.6.4 for 10.1
tensorflow 2.1.0
tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0

I ran (tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')), it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This thread (link added) in which they mentioned its device 0 (basically the device ID which the system identifies as primary GPU)

[Tensorflow not detecting GPU - Adding visible gpu devices: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094789/tensorflow-not-detecting-gpu-adding-visible-gpu-devices-0)

framework error might be because of the TensorFlow version, Try using a more recent version.

Comment: Hey thanks I think it was. so I looked around and tried tensorflow 2.3.0 and its gpu 2.3.0, it created tensorflow device but now it gave me another error ** tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1ebcc2d0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>,
num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device**

Comment: i am not sure if this is the problem: 1) when i use tensorflow 2.1.0, it gave me the duplicate node error maybe because there is a problem with import tensorflow.keras as it cannot be resolved. 2) That import issue is gone with tensorflow 2.3.0, but it gave me the no kernel image error, i think 2.3.0 isnt compatible with window 7 according to the tensorflow website. Is there a way to fix the import issue with tensorflow 2.1.0?

Comment: have you tried running the code in a virtual environment 
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42055)

Comment: I have not, but why does that matter? my code works if i dont use GPU, meaning if i purposely use tensorflow 2.3.0 with the wrong version of CUDNN, it will skip GPU device and use the CPU, its just really, really slow. But now iwant to get the GPU device to work - its able to build the device, but there is some unknown incompatibility issues